# Does a forked process copy all mapped memory when writing?

Tags: linux, c, fork, mmap

I understand that a forked process maps the parent's memory and copies it when writing to it. Does it copy just what it needs written or does it copy the entire mapped memory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Neither. The kernel copies a full page. The size of a page depends on the architecture you're using (and architectures these days usually support multiple page sizes). If you're running on a x86 64-bit architecture, 4KiB is the most likely size.

**Longer answer**:
The kernel and hardware virtual memory systems deal with memory by slices called pages. The default page size on x86 64-bit architecture is 4KiB for example.

During `fork()` most of the parent memory space is shared with the child. This memory space is composed of pages. Each shared page is marked read-only by the kernel during `fork()`.

After `fork()` is complete, if *either* the parent or the child tries to modify the memory, the hardware generates a page fault because the page is marked read-only. A page fault is a CPU exception that traps into the kernel (i.e the current program execution stops and the cpu starts executing a predefined exception handler in the kernel).

The kernel then determines that it's a copy on write fault and allocates a new page. This page is marked read/write, the content of the previous page is copied onto it. The kernel then maps it into the memory space. The process execution is then resumed at the trapping instruction: the instruction that triggered the fault is executed again. This time the page is marked read/write, so the instruction completes without faulting.

This process will repeat itself every time either the child or the parent writes to a shared page. After a CoW fault has occurred for a page, it is usually still marked read-only in the "other" process (it depends on the kernel implementation). If this process tries write to it, a fault will be generated like before. But the kernel will notice that the page is not shared anymore and simply mark it read/write.

Answer (score -2):

In 1988 SunOS-4.0 introduced the modern `mmap()` implementation. All modern OS reimplemented this concepts from SunOS-4.0. Since that time, the `fork()` call is typically a copy on write variant.

If you write access memory that was mapped in a shared way by the parent process, this remains shared in the child. If you write access private memory, this is replaced by a private copy while you try to modify it.